# FSB versus CPU clock

Tags: cpu, motherboard, fsb

I can't give additional information about next two CPUs that I want to compare.

I have two CPUs on my hand,

```
1) Intel Pentium 4 - 2800 Mhz with 133 FSB
2) Intel Celeron - 1700 Mhz with 400 FSB
```

Will second CPU work faster because it has more FSB then first one?

Comment: The Pentium 4 actually has a faster FSB speed the celeron is showing the Quad-pumped rate the actual clock rate for the FSB is 100Mhz.

Comment: @Lamar B and my Intel Core 2 Duo has 200 MHz FSB but only 1.8 GHz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the FSB is not the only part of how fast a CPU can perform calculations.

The FSB determines how fast the CPU can *get* data from memory, but the clock speed of the CPU determines how fast it can *deal* with that information once it has gotten it.

In this case I would probably expect the Pentium 4 to be faster, but it depends on many other factors.  There have been many generation of Intel products that have borne the Celeron (aka "cheap") brand name.

Comparing FSB speed is only really useful if you are comparing two near-identical processors that have the same clock speed but different FSB speeds